# Replace two characters using one sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to remove the `=` and `]` characters using one sed command:

```
# echo "A=[A]" | sed s'/[=\]]/ /g'
A=[A]
```

Something is wrong with this syntax?

I Expect the following results from sed

```
# echo "A=[A]" | ....sed 
A [A
```

Comment: Should that expected result have one space in it or two or none?  Because it currently has one, and those other options require slightly different solutions.

Comment: If you want the result to replace every occurrence of "[" and "A" with a space, I'd use `tr`. One of those "using the wrong tool (i.e, overly complex) for the job" situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo "A=[A]" | sed s'/[]=]/ /g'`

A [A

Answer (score 9):

You can use the '-e' flag to execute multiple substitutes, for example:

```
# echo "A = [A]" | sed -e 's/=//' -e 's/]//'
A  [A
```

It might be possible to match both '=' and ']' in a single substitute but even if it is, I don't think it'll provide much benefit over using '-e'.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably easier to use [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to do something like this as it doesn't involve messing with REs

```
echo "A=[A]<-" | tr "]=" " "
A [A <-
```